# Cómo seleccionar campos de una tabla MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Básicamente quiero seleccionar todos los campos que yo quiero (que no son todos) de una tabla MySQL con PHP. El código que tengo es:

```
 $query="SELECT Marketplace, IdPedido, fecha, nombre cliente as nombre, direccion, DNI, CP, poblacion, provincia
        from pedidos";

        $rs_pedidos_WS=mysqli_query($conWebService, $query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs_pedidos_WS)){
            echo $row['Marketplace'];
```

El caso es que me da el siguiente error: " mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given" y no comprendo por qué. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: verifica el campo nombre_cliente que este bien escrito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te está diciendo es `boolean given`, esto quiere decir que se ha pasado un booleano en vez de un array que es lo que la función `mysqli_fetch_array` espera recibir.

Consejos:

- Controla y maneja los errores en un handler de errores como `die()` o `mysqli_error()`
- Aprende a utilizar la lógica a tu favor y revisa a ver si lo que estas solicitando realmente es un recurso alcanzable (a reachable resource)
- El flujo de aprendizaje y mejora de programación es el siguiente: Lee, Aprende, Practica, Busca y Mejora.

Ahora te escribiré un código de ejemplo con comentarios para que sepas cómo puede mejorar tu código si aplicas los consejos que te menciono más arriba:

```
<?php
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";
    $db = "";
    $conWebService = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    /* comprobamos si hay conexion */
    if($conWebService){
        $sql=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT Marketplace, IdPedido, fecha, nombre cliente 
 As nombre, direccion, DNI, CP, poblacion, provincia FROM pedidos");
        /* ¿La consulta se ejecutó bien? */
        if($sql){

            $filaSql=mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            echo $filaSql["Marketplace"];

        }else{
            echo mysqli_error($conWebService);   
        }

    }else{

        echo "Error: La conexión no existe";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
 $user = "root";
    $pass = "mypass";
    $host = "localhost";
    $db = "mybd";
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$sql = "SELECT Marketplace, IdPedido, fecha, nombre cliente as nombre, direccion, DNI, CP, poblacion, provincia from pedidos";
$res = $con->query($sql);
   
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
      echo "<p>".$row["Marketplace"]."</p>";
    }
```

Utilizando  la función query de $con ejecuta la consulta.
Suerte.